# Why do I have multiple gradle wrapper distributions downloaded (of the same version)?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, gradlew

I'm looking around in my `~/.gradle` folder (relocated to `P:\caches\gradle`, which doesn't affect this behaviour) and I found some strange folders.

In the past I have updated multiple projects from 2.0 to 2.1 via running `gradle wrapper` which updated `project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`

I just found out that for some reason the exact same `distributionUrl` zip file was downloaded multiple times. As you can see they all have the same size and I did a binary diff, they're the same bit by bit except the timestamps:

[image]

The contents of each folder above look like this:

[image]

I just updated from 2.2 to 2.2.1 and it happened again: this time it's 2 folders not 3. Does anyone know why this happens?

I'm using Gradle from both IntelliJ Idea and the command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there are multiple copies for the same version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617070/why-there-are-multiple-copies-for-the-same-version-of-gradle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gradle retains multiple copies of Gradle distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339270/gradle-retains-multiple-copies-of-gradle-distributions)