# .gradle retains multiple copies of Gradle distributions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using the Gradle wrapper to build various projects and noticed that my `.gradle` directory now contains multiple copies of each Gradle distribution. Each copy is in a unique subdirectory as shown:

[image]

This has happened with every version of Gradle that I have under `.gradle`, up through `gradle-2.2.1-all`. Why do these copies exist and how are they selected by the Gradle wrapper?

The only evidence I've found is the Gradle documentation for [distributionUrl](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper:distributionUrl):

> The wrapper downloads a certain distribution only once and caches it.

These subdirectories may be a hash computed from the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`. `http` and `https` variants of the URL could contribute up to two copies, which is the number of copies that most of my distributions have. That doesn't explain the third copy in `gradle-1.12-all` though.

Comment: The folder name is indeed a hash computed from the URL value. It could be something as simple as the wrapper properties file using different character encodings.

Comment: It's an open issue: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3196

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there are multiple copies for the same version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617070/why-there-are-multiple-copies-for-the-same-version-of-gradle)